# gnuradio-companion flooding console with the letter D

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I'm running a very simple flow graph in GNU Radio Companion, consisting of a USRP Source, which is connected to (1) a quadrature demod that is connected to a wxgui scope sink and (2) a wxgui fft sink. These display and draw the expected results, but at the same time the console portion gets flooded with the letter D which slows down the GUI elements until they stop responding. From the console output:

Generating: "/home/gnuradio/top_block.py"

Executing: "/home/gnuradio/top_block.py"

linux; GNU C++ version 4.7.3; Boost_104900; UHD_003.005.004-0-unknown

Using Volk machine: ssse3_64
-- Opening a USRP2/N-Series device...
-- Current recv frame size: 1472 bytes
-- Current send frame size: 1472 bytes
-- Detecting internal GPSDO.... not found

UHD Warning:
    Unable to set the thread priority. Performance may be negatively affected.
    Please see the general application notes in the manual for instructions.
    EnvironmentError: OSError: error in pthread_setschedparam
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD...

where the Ds repeat until the flow graph is terminated. Unfortunately, single-letter error codes (assuming that's what these are) are extremely difficult to search for online!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its indicating an overflow.

"When UHD software detects the overflow, it prints an 'O' or 'D'"

Here's the documentation: http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_general.html#general_ounotes